# Connecting to and viewing data from Active Directory with Razor/MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, active-directory

I'm pretty new to Razor/MVC (and StackOverflow!), but I recently started a project at an internship and could use some advice. Basically, I am responsible for making web forms that users can fill out, and this info is stored in a queue table. Once approved by the DBA team, this data is inserted into several tables in the main DB. The good news is I already figured out most of this. However, the one thing I seem to be struggling with is the Active Directory.

I want this form to allow a user to enter search terms (last names or usernames), return a list of AD accounts, and then be able to select multiple accounts in order to grant various permissions.

I have a coworkers somewhat related code to use as reference, but it is just C# and not Razor/MVC. I believe I can learn from that code to connect to the AD, use PrincipalContext to bind the data, search it, etc. and return the info as a DataTable (note: still waiting on permission to access AD and make sure I'm using the correct LDAP  path). But I am not sure how to implement this code. Should it all go in the controller? I thought all the data should be passed from the model? I know how to connect to, query, and update SQL Server databases in MVC. But that was easy--there are plenty of tutorials and VS can make the CRUD views, and so on. This is different, and I'm having trouble finding good resources that explain everything clearly.

This is alreadly longer than I envisioned...so basically I'm trying to find out:

-How/which part of the MVC should connect to the AD (model or controller? Both? How should those parts communicate?)

-How to actually pass this data to the View? (And as DataTable, DataView, WebGrid, etc.?)

Also: Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Razor/MVC3. I have some experience in Java, but to be perfectly honest I'm not great at programming (hopefully I can help change that over the course of this internship though!). I can try and post some of my code too, although that may have to wait until I get into work tomorrow. I hope this isn't too long or too general.. Thanks in advance for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How/which part of the MVC should connect to the AD (model or
>   controller? Both? How should those parts communicate?)

***Controller*** - in this part of MVC arch occur the ***Logic*** of your ***Application***.
Only in the Controller happen the interaction between ***Active Directory***.

The Model is the source of Object often retrieve and store model state in a database. To the controller, model is the reference of what object looks like in order to work  with **View**.

[image: The MVC framework includes the following components]

To your next question you need a lot of examples and explanation to learned it.
Try to go here : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's stuff I had read over before, but slipped my mind over the course of the project. Re-reading and thinking about it again definitely helped.

Comment: Now the funny part...I've apparently been overthinking this task and actually don't need to worry about AD stuff at all. I do have another question if you have time though... In this same form, I need the user to be able to enter multiple names and details for accounts that will eventually need access to specific DBs. The trouble is I do not know how to allow a user to request permissions for a variable number of accounts for one specific database. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: And in case I wasn't clear, by enter the info I just mean it should be stored as rows in a separate table, each tuple just linked to the correct DB via foreign key. Hope I'm not spamming your inbox or something with all these messages...